# Copying appended data of the file to another file in a real time

Tags: bash

I have file **original.cap**, that is constantly getting new binary data and is incsreasing itself. How can I in a real time copy new data comming to **original.cap** to another file **copy.cap**.
Is it possible to do it in a bash?
I was thinking of doing some redirection, like with curl library this way:

```
curl -K original.cap >> copy.cap
```

Comment: `tail -f original.cap > copy.cap` ? What kind of file is the original.cap? Is it stored on your computer? Is it on external server and that's why you use curl?

Comment: Yes, original.cap is on my computer.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks a lot. It works great. You can post it as an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to "follow" the [changes in] file.

The standard utility [tail](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) with `--follow` does:

> -f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
>                 output appended data as the file grows;

So `tail -f` will output the data from the file as the file grows.